# How to create a look up table for different range of values

Tags: c, opencv

I'm want to try using look up table (cvLUT) to check whether it is fast than the current way that I'm doing right now. The question is I don't really understand how look up table works if I have different set of values Eg.

```
if(mean < 50)
 //do gamma correction
else if(mean > 50 && mean < 100)
 // do gamma correction
else 
 //do do gamma correction
```

I saw that we need to calculate the look up table first but the mean is calculated locally using local window. How can I do that? I tried stored the mean values in the vector and then use it but it is very slow when it's stored in the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a lookup table is appropriate for what you are doing since the transformation is dependent on information in the local window.  A lookup table is good if you want a transformation on all pixels that only depends on the pixel value and doesn't depend on the value of other pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is what you're looking for then it would be hard to beat inline assembly.

```
int mean;

asm {
cmp mean, 99
jg _else      
cmp mean, 50
jl _if
_else_if:
}
// gamma correction
asm { _else: }
// gamma correction
asm { _if: }
// gamma correction
```